# Merge query returns -1 instead of number of rows merged

Tags: c#, oracle, merge, devart

We have an old application that runs against an Oracle database and makes use of DataSets, DataTables and TableAdapters. It uses the now deprecated System.Data.OracleClient and we are looking to replace this dll with those from DevArt.

I used the Oracle Migration Wizard to migrate from System.Data.OracleClient to Devart.Data.Oracle. After the migration, all queries continue to work just fine, except one type: MERGE queries. They still merge records just fine (the expected records are inserted/updated). However, previously the number of records merged was returned, but now it always returns "-1" instead.

Any idea what the issue could be? Preferable without having to manually update all merge queries (there are a lot of them), but if updating all queries is the only way to solve this that is acceptable.

The code that handles the connecting to the database is generated by the DataSet file:

```
Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand command = "MERGE INTO [...]";
System.Data.ConnectionState previousConnectionState = command.Connection.State;
if ((command.Connection.State & System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
    command.Connection.Open();
    int returnValue;
    try
    {
        returnValue = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (previousConnectionState != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            command.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
return returnValue;
```

Comment: This Post on SO may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601304/oracle-merge-statement-not-sticking-using-devart-dotconnect-for-oracle

Comment: @RameshBabu Different problem: the merge does 'stick' in my case (updates and inserts do happen). I have a problem with the return value. That being said, I tried the mentioned solution, but adding Direct=true to the connection string only makes the application fail to connect at all.

Comment: Add a piece of code, which may help you to get answers.

Comment: @Exhausted Its code generated by the dataset, but I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an article about migration from oracle client to devart. He basically says "this is how devart works". You can find details below:

> Devart can return the number of affected rows only for INSERT, UPDATE
>   and DELETE DML commands, in all the other cases it returns -1. We used
>   these return values sometimes in our api to indicate whether the
>   operation was successful or not. With these 3 DML commands it is ok.
>   We have several usages of oracle’s MERGE command too, OracleClient can
>   return the correct number of affected rows, devart returns -1. We
>   changed our API where MERGE is used to not count on the return value.

to read full article, click [here](http://coder21.blogspot.com.tr/2014/04/migration-from-systemdataoracleclient.html)

Comment: Sadly, it seems that 'does not work, replace with UPDATE/INSERT' is the only feasable solution in my case.

Comment: Changing something at infrastructure level is always painful... Hope you will find a better way but for now it seems like you need to stick with it.

Answer (score 2):

In ODP.NET `ExecuteNonQuery` for Oracle statement `merge` also returns `-1`. 
The only workaround I know is to call it in PLSQL block and use `SQL%ROWCOUNT`, like here:

```
  string sql =
      "begin " +
      "  merge into test t1 " +
      "    using (select col1, col2 from test) t2 on (t2.col1=t1.col1) " +
      "    when matched then update set col2=col2+1; " +
      "  :num := sql%rowcount; "+
      "end;";
  OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, myConnection);
  var p = cmd.Parameters.Add(":num", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  Console.WriteLine("Rows affected: " + p.Value);

--------------------------
Sample output for my data: 
Rows affected: 2
```

I hope you'll get/find better answers for Devart.